# In chorme horizontal scroll work , but in safari browser its not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, safari, mobile-safari

here is my code
**this code not work on safari.**

targetPosition i set the scroll value, for example , 11 , 22, 33 , where i scroll

```
  function ScrollToActiveTab(item, id, useraction) {
    if (item !== null && item !== undefined && useraction) {
      dispatch(addCurrentMenu(item));
    }
  
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // Ensure this runs after any pending layout changes
      var scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollableDiv');
      let tempId = 'targetId-' + id;
      var targetElement = document.getElementById(tempId);
  
      if (targetElement) {
        var targetPosition = targetElement.offsetLeft + targetElement.clientWidth / 2 - window.innerWidth / 2;
  
        // Perform the scroll
        scrollableDiv.scrollLeft = targetPosition;
      }
    });
  }
```

Please guide my why ° scrollableDiv.scrollLeft = targetPosition;° not work on safari. Thanks

i want work  scrollableDiv.scrollLeft = targetPosition , in safari also
see attachment , i have a menu list once i click i update tragetPosition

[menu Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzkGa.png)

Comment: Please define "_its not work_".

Comment: Yes this code not work on safari.

Comment: check what `targetPosition` actually is, compared to what you think it should be

Comment: but what does "not work" mean? does it not scroll at all? scroll incorrectly? show an error in the console? burn your house down?

Comment: targetPosition i set the scroll value, for example , 11 , 22, 33 , where i scroll

Comment: What do you mean when you say the code is not working? What you expect it to do, and what it does instead? Do you get any errors?

Comment: and you've confirmed that `targetPosition` is the value you expect? I mean, it's based on a calculation, so you don't set it to 11, 22, 33 at all - it's a calculated value - I'm asking is the calculated value the value you expect it to be

Comment: i update question and add attachment , scrollableDiv.scrollLeft = targetPosition; here value not update and targetPosition also 0 , always in safari

Comment: even i am doing  scrollableDiv.scrollLeft =22, its also not scroll.

Comment: Please anybody can help me on it , am new on it . Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please help ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything that runs Sufari - and even if I did, your code is not complete enough to help, since we can't see your HTML for example, or your CSS for that matter